# d3-wordcloud in GWT

Tags: java, node.js, d3.js, gwt

I am trying to use d3-wordcloud(https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud)  in my GWT project. I included this in my .html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Where 'main.js' has a method which contains this code:

```
    d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
      .timeInterval(20)
      .words(word_entries)
      .fontSize(function(d) { return xScale(+d.value); })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();
```

When I try to call the method from the .html file, the word cloud is generated fine. But when I do it from a java file (with $wnd), I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d3.layout.cloud is not a function' error
```

I think this might be because the d3.layout.cloud.js is written in node js and GWT doesn't know how to work with it.

Is that the reason? Is there a workaround?

Additional info: I use GWT 2.7. Good with java. Zero node js skills!

Comment: What do you mean with "with $wnd"? Can you include this GWT code?

Comment: Your problem is probably related with how you are using $wnd, but you need to include the source code to see why it fail. Also, it is a good idea to activate on exception breakpoint and see if d3 has loaded cloud correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like you need to simply use `cloud()...` instead of `d3.layout.cloud()...`

See line 10: https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/node.js